# Script to delete multiple users

Tags: users

I want to delete all users except 2 of them. First, I put all the existing usernames in a file with `ls /home > usernames` and manually delete the users I want to keep. Then I create this simple script :

```
for user in 'cat usernames'
do
     userdel -r $user
done
```

But when I execute the script it shows me the `userdel` manual, like if I'm doing a wrong use of the command. What's wrong with my script?

Comment: The command your script runs is: `userdel -r cat usernames`

Comment: The problem is the wrong sort of single quotes. You want the backquote, often to be found close to the ESC key. Using the more modern form `for user in $(cat usernames)`  will fix it as well. There is also the `for user in $(< usernames)` form.

Comment: If you want to process a file line by line, never use something like `for user in $(cat usernames)`. Instead use `while IFS= read -r user; do something ; done < usernames`

Comment: @Bodo Why is that better?

Comment: The shell will perform word splitting on the output of `cat file`. In simple cases it often works correct, but you can get strange results if the input file contains spaces, backslashes or other special characters. See [BashFAQ#001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F001.How_can_I_read_a_file_.28data_stream.2C_variable.29_line-by-line_.28and.2For_field-by-field.29.3F),  https://stackoverflow.com/q/17099860/10622916 and maybe https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls